# OpenGL Fog does not appear

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glut

I wanted to create a coordinate system with some lines in it, and wanted to display one window with depth-fog.

My "fog-code" looks like this:

```
glEnable(GL_FOG);
float fogColor[4] = {0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1};
glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, GL_LINEAR);
glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor); 
glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY,0.8); 
glHint(GL_FOG_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glFogf(GL_FOG_START,0.1); 
glFogf(GL_FOG_END,200);
```

and is placed in my main function (don't know yet if this could cause any problems, but just to be sure), right after the init()-call and before my display-function-call.

Update:

The problem was actually really simple: My problem was, that I worked solely on the `GL_MODELVIEW`-matrix, thinking there was no real difference to the `GL_PROJECTION`-matrix. According to [this article](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) and the post from Reto Koradi, there is a pretty significant difference. I hugely recommend reading the full article to better understand the system behind OpenGL (definitely helped me a lot).

The corrected code (for my init()-call) would then be:

```
void init2()
{
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); // set background color to white
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // switch to projection mode
    glLoadIdentity(); // initialize a projection matrix
    glOrtho(-300, 300, -300, 300, -800, 800); // map coordinates to the viewport 
    gluLookAt(2,2,10, 0,0,-0.5, 0,1,0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // now switch to modelview mode
}
```

Comment: Such difficulties a good example for how seemingly simple fixed GL pipeline programming can make things quite not so simple. Like @datenwolf I recommend strongly that to you switch to modern GL and mix the fog in pixel-by-pixel in the fragment shader, because then, the GPU will do those calculations, which you may now try to do manually just to find fitting parameters for the calls to the fixed pipeline functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fog equation is evaluated based on the value of (quote from OpenGL 2.1 spec):

> Otherwise, if the fog source is FRAGMENT DEPTH, then c is the eye-coordinate distance from the eye, (0,0,0,1) in eye coordinates, to the fragment center.

`FRAGMENT_DEPTH` is the default, so this applies in your case. Eye coordinate refers to the coordinates after the model-view transformation has been applied. So it's the distance from the origin after applying the model-view transform. The spec also allows implementations to use the absolute value of the z-coordinate instead of the distance from the origin.

One small observation on your code: `GL_FOG_DENSITY` does not matter if the mode is `GL_LINEAR`. It is only used for the exponential modes.

For `GL_LINEAR` mode, the behavior is pretty much as you would expect. The original fragment color is linearly blended with the fog color within the range `GL_FOG_START` to `GL_FOG_END`. So everything smaller than `GL_FOG_START` has the original fragment color, everything after `GL_FOG_END` has the fog color, and the values in between are linear interpolations between the two, with gradually more fog color and less original fragment color.

To get good results, you'll have to play with the `GL_FOG_START` and `GL_FOG_END` values. If you don't get as much for as desired, you can start by reducing the value of `GL_FOG_END`.

I peeked at the linked code, and noticed one problem: You're specifying the projection matrix while you're in `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix mode. You need to be careful that you specify the matrices in the correct matrix mode, which is `GL_PROJECTION` for the projection matrix.

Mixing up the matrix modes does not have an adverse effect on the resulting vertex coordinates, since both the model-view and projection matrices are applied to the vertices. So for very simple use, you can sometimes get away with using the wrong mode. But once lighting comes into play, it is critical to use the correct matrix mode, since lighting calculations are done after the model-view transformation has been applied, but before the projection transformation.

And yes, as others already pointed out, a lot of this actually gets simpler if you write your own shaders. The fact that I quoted the OpenGL 2.1 spec is probably a hint that this functionality is old and obsolete.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the
`glLoadIdentity();` call, but i thought it simply loaded the identity matrix for the current transformation matrix, regardless of `GL_MODELVIEW ` or `GL_PROJECTION` (the comment was used from a previous project, so sorry for that....)
Or did I get this wrong? Also, the problem is, that I literally see no difference, even with using GL_LINEAR (which should certainly show something)

Comment: @dennlinger The problem with the matrix modes is that you call `glOrtho()` while you're in `GL_MODELVIEW` mode. That call needs to be made in `GL_PROJECTION` mode.

Comment: this was indeed the problem. With the call in `GL_PROJECTION` and afterwards switching to`GL_MODELVIEW` it actually displays something. Thanks again! I will link the solution to the original post

Answer (score 1):

Like to many things that OpenGL-1.1 did, fog is calculated on a per vertex level. So if you have a long line, with only two points, fog is calculated only for the end points and then the color interpolated linear inbetween. Depending on how your line is aligned and which shading mode you use, this may result in no apparent fogging.

Two solutions:

- Subdivide the lines into a couple of dozen line segments, so to sample the fog at more than two points.

or

- Use a fragment shader instead and calculate the fog term therein. This is what I suggest doing.

Comment: With `GL_FOG_HINT` set to `GL_NICEST`, which is in the posted code, the fog is evaluated per fragment.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: …if, and only if the implementation supports it. From the reference: `GL_FOG_HINT
                    
                        Indicates the accuracy of fog calculation.
                        If per-pixel fog calculation is not efficiently supported
                        by the GL implementation,
                        hinting GL_DONT_CARE or GL_FASTEST can result in per-vertex
                        calculation of fog effects.
                    `

Comment: First, thanks for your quick answer. According to your post, you are saying that I should see some differences at the startpoint  and the endpoint (since I draw coordinate axes, too, at least there should be a visible difference). But not even that is visible right now.